# First and Follow Set of a given CFG

Tags: compiler-construction, set

I have this CFG and there is a loop in it then how to make first and follow set of looped cfg as first sets are easy but having problem in follow sets

```
S -> iEtSS'|a
S' -> es
E -> b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I fixed the question as you might be asking answer for this question.*

```
S -> iEtSS'|a<br>
S' -> eS|eplison<br>
E -> b
```

***First***

```
First(S) -> {i, a}<br>
First(S') -> {e, eplison}<br>
First(E) -> {b}
```

***Follow***

```
Follow(S) -> {$, First(S')} -> {$, e}<br>
Follow(S') -> {Follow(S)} -> {$, e}<br>
Follow(E) -> {t}
```

Even if there is a loop it possibly can't have more than above non terminal in *Follow set*.

You may have seen loop as

```
Follow(S) -> {$, First(S'), Follow(S)}
->Follow(S) is because First(S') has eplison.
```